# Does homeomorphism between cones imply homeomorphism between sections

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

For any topological space $A$, the cone $C(A)$ is defined to be $A \times [0,\infty)$ with $A \times 0$ identified to a point (cone point).

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two compact Hausdorff spaces such that there is a homeomorphism between $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ which preserves the cone points. Can we prove that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: In [On a problem of S. Ulam concerning Cartesian products](https://eudml.org/doc/213133), Fox gave (see figure 1, p. 284) an example of two spaces $A,B$ which are not homeomorphic such that $A \times [0,1]$ and $B \times [0,1]$ are homeomorphic. The example is exceedingly simple: $A$ and $B$ are each the union in the plane of an annulus with two line segments; in $A$ the line segments are both attached to the "outside" while in $B$ one is attached to the inside and one to the outside. Unfortunately, the homeomorphism $A \times [0,1] \cong B \times [0,1]$ doesn't descend to a cone homeomorphism

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $X$, $Y$ be any two smoothly h-cobordant closed manifolds of dimension $\ge 4$ that are non-homeomorphic. For example, we can take $X=S^2\times L(7,1)$ and $Y=S^2\times L(7,2)$ where as usual $L(p,q)$ is a 3-dimensional lens space. By the weak h-cobordism theorem the interior of the h-cobordism is diffeomorphic to $X\times\mathbb R$ and also to $Y\times \mathbb R$. The interior is two-ended, and we can compactify it by adding two points (= the ends). The "identity" homeomorphism  $X\times\mathbb R\to Y\times \mathbb R$ extends to
a homeomorphism of the compactifications that takes ends to ends. Removing the points corresponding to one end gives a homeomorphism from the cone over $X$ to the cone over $Y$ that preserves the cone point.

Conversely, if $X$, $Y$ are closed manifolds and $X\times\mathbb R$ is diffeomorphic to $Y\times \mathbb R$, then $X$, $Y$ are h-cobordant.

The same trick of course works when $X$, $Y$ are compact non-homeomorphic spaces and $X\times\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $Y\times \mathbb R$.

Comment: Do you know if dimension ≥4 is necessary here?  This is a nice example, but it would be nicer still if there was a simple low-dimensional example like the one @TimCampion quotes in comments for the same question with cylinders instead of cones.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: It seem hard (impossible?) to get examples where $X, Y$ are low-dimensional manifolds (even with boundary). For more general compact spaces I suspect examples exist, but you have to ask a point set topologist. What I wanted to point out in the above answer is that $X$ is recovered from $X\times\mathbb R$ only up to h-cobordism, and this is a standard and important fact.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, can you clarify the statement and application of the weak h-cobordism theorem in this non-simply connected setting?

Comment: @BadEnglish The weak h-cobordsim theorem works for any fundamental group. It says that any h-cobordsim of dimension at least 5 becomes a product after removing one boundary component.

Comment: @BadEnglish: you can read on the weak h-cobordsim theorem e.g. in theorem 3.1.8 of https://sites.calvin.edu/venema/embeddingsbook/embeddings-noprint.pdf, "Embeddings in manifolds" by Daverman and Venema, It is a consequence of Stallings' engulfing. There are also topological and smooth versions. See also Siebenmann's paper on open collars, https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0246301-9/S0002-9947-1969-0246301-9.pdf.